# How to select data object from select option and use it other drop down in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have list of Object, its source of drop down. On selection of Select Scenario drop down (ScenarioData.name), then we need to show  enabled: []  of ScenarioData  of same object in Select Env dropdown.  How to do this.

On form submit we need to pass both selected name and selected Env from drop down.

```
export interface ScenarioData {
    id: number;
    item: string;
    name: string;
    enabled: [];
    menu: string;
    menuScenario: string
}

<mat-form-field *ngIf="scenariosObservable | async as scenarios">
    <mat-label>Select Scenario</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let scenario of scenarios" [value]= "scenario">{{scenario.name}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select> 
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Select Environment</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(value)]="envselected">
        <mat-option [value]= "env" *ngFor="let env of selectedValue.enabled">{{env}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: And what exactly is the issue that you're facing?

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'enabled' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (SearchbyscenarioComponent.html:13)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23911)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23307)

Comment: @KGowda have you try any of the answers ?

Answer (score 0):

Just place an `*ngIf="selectedValue"` in the second form field. This would make sure that the second drop down is not rendered onto the screen unless the `selectedValue`  is initialized.

Here, give this a try:

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="selectedValue">
  <mat-label>Select Environment</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="envselected">
    <mat-option 
      [value]="env" 
      *ngFor="let env of selectedValue.enabled">
      {{env}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way by useing safe navigation operator (?.)

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Select Environment</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(value)]="envselected">
        <mat-option [value]= "env" 
            *ngFor="let env of selectedValue?.enabled">
                 {{env}}
         </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```